# Destructuring an array and its properties at the same time

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is it possible to destructure elements of an array while also destructuring some of its properties as an object ?

For example, the following code compiles but doesn't give the expected result :

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]
array.myvalue = 'test'

function f([a, b, ...{ myvalue }]) {
  console.log(a, b, myvalue);
}

f(array)
```

Output :

```
1 2 undefined
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @mplungjan I suppose  `1 2 "test"`

Comment: @Strebler what about this syntax ? https://jsfiddle.net/u72wfcra/ I know it doesn't give "exactly" what you want x)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy This does not work. You just collect the remaining part of the array.

Comment: @Strebler yeah yeah fine :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for destructuring with wanted indices and the named property.

```js
function f({ 0: a, 1: b, myvalue }) {
    console.log(a, b, myvalue);
}

const array = [1, 2, 3]

array.myvalue = 'test'

f(array)
```

Comment: Yep, I have actually thought of that, but I was wondering if there was a syntax where we can also benefit from the classic array destructuring syntax. If there's nothing better, I'll mark this answer as accepted.